# Azure DevOps container jobs; run commandline commands on a 'second' imnage

Tags: azure-devops

I am playing around with Azure DevOps container jobs and service containers. My use case is as follows, I (unfortunately) have to do everything on Private Hosted Build agents.

I am running my job as a container job in Container A. 
I have specific software installed (Fortify), which uses commandline, on Container B

Basically I want one of the steps running on container A to be run in Container B (to do the fortify scan, using the code from the workspace). Of course I could do it in a separate job, but I'd prefer to do it in the same job.

Any ideas if this is possible at the moment?

Thanks

Comment: If this steo's doing different things in A and B then separate it could be a better choice. Or, you can set step target https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#step-target if this's what you want? Also try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#multiple-jobs that you can set different containers for the same step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that step target seem to be what I need. 
In the below answer I read that this is new for sprint 163 release.. But cool, exactly what I needed!

Comment: My pleasure to help, but this is not an answer in fact but a comment. I have posted my answer and you can accept it as the answer if you wish. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, I just read that this feature will be available in the sprint 163 release!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-163-update

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: python
    image: python:3.8
  - container: node
    image: node:13.2

jobs:
- job: example
  container: python

  steps:
  - script: echo Running in the job container

  - script: echo Running on the host
    target: host

  - script: echo Running in another container, in restricted commands mode
    target:
      container: node
      commands: restricted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Step target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#step-target) to choose which container or host the step will running at.

For example:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: pycontainer
    image: python:3.8

steps:
- task: SampleTask@1
  target: host
- task: AnotherTask@1
  target: pycontainer
```

Comment: I took my own answer as accepted answer. I couldn't get step target to work so I have the feeling that it'll be released in the 163 release. Then again I could be wrong. Anyway good to know about this, thanks!